# Cannot read ASP localhost, plus problems with virtual directories

Tags: asp.net, web-config, localhost

When going to http://localhost/ on my personal machine, I get a blank screen.

I have a site at `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/` but the contents of that folder aren't listed like they should be.

I tried going directly for the site, and I got this error:
[image]

Line 16 is the error

```
15:         <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
16:         <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
17:         <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

Removing the line from the Web.config doesn't seem to help. The error persists and even claims the line wasn't removed. I made sure I saved my edit.

I then tried making a Virtual Directory and going there. The exact same error showed up.
I added the proper user with the needed rights, but that didn't seem to do anything.
[image]

So there are 2 problems here: Localhost won't list folders and this error I keep getting.

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: code added

Comment: Classic ASP or ASP.NET? Have you run aspnet_regiis.exe? Have you enabled the ISAPI filter?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `Config source` panel in the error page? That screenshot is frustratingly difficult to read...

Comment: ASP.NET. Haven't run that, don't know what it is really.

Comment: Frédéric, just drag the screenshot on to a new tab and enlarge it.

Comment: Frédéric, I ran it with -i and -enable, no changes. Perhaps I should restart

Comment: @WebDevHobo to notify someone of new comment, use "@" e.g. @Frédéric otherwise he won't see it in the inbox.

Comment: Didn't know that. So, @Frédéric Hamidi and @Oded, new comments.

Comment: @WebDevHobo, the request URL is strange, the space character between `01` and `WebConfigDemo` should be escaped AFAICT. What happens if you relocate your site into a folder that doesn't have a space in its name? While we're at it, what happens if you rename your `web.config` file (since it looks like IIS isn't reading that one)?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi Removed the space, no difference. I renamed the web.config file to some random keyboardmasshing, and now it actually works. That is to say: the site displays. http://localhost/ still isn't giving an overview.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the blank localhost

did you put a default page in the wwwroot folder ?

regarding the line 16 error

is there a space in the website name?

can you send the whole web.config

Comment: There was a .htm file, I deleted it, nothing changed. There was a space. I removed it, changed nothing. However, changing the name of the web.config file did display the site.

Comment: Another thing: I just noticed there is a folder called "aspnet_client". It contains folders for version 2 and version 4. Both folders are empty.